# Catching fatal PHP errors

Tags: php, fatal-error, shutdown

I am trying to make an errorhandler in PHP that catches fatal errors.
Catching normal errors works! Fortunately!

But fatal errors is still a no go.

Could anyone please tell me what the problem is with my script below:
Thanks a million. *If so it means it has saved my day :-#*

```
function shutdown(){
        $isError = false;
        if($error = error_get_last()){
            switch($error['type']){
                case E_ERROR:
                case E_CORE_ERROR:
                case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
                case E_USER_ERROR:
                    $isError = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if ($isError){
            echo "Script execution halted ({$error['message']})";
        }
        else {
            echo "Script completed";
        }
}


set_error_handler('errorHandler');
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');





function errorHandler( $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext){
  echo 'Into '.__FUNCTION__.'() at line '.__LINE__.
  "\n\n---ERRNO---\n". print_r( $errno, true).
  "\n\n---ERRSTR---\n". print_r( $errstr, true).
  "\n\n---ERRFILE---\n". print_r( $errfile, true).
  "\n\n---ERRLINE---\n". print_r( $errline, true).
  "\n\n---ERRCONTEXT---\n".print_r( $errcontext, true).
  "\n\nBacktrace of errorHandler()\n".
  print_r( debug_backtrace(), true);
}

function a( ){
  //echo "a()'s backtrace\n".print_r( debug_backtrace(), true);
  echo 'asdfasdf; // oops
}

function b(){
  //echo "b()'s backtrace\n".print_r( debug_backtrace(), true);
  a();
}

b();
?>
```

Parse errors should be catchable imho since I already used a pre baked script that catches parse errors. Unfortunately though, the script is quite buggy.

Comment: Is the parse error intentional? PHP won't try to run code with parse errors.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: PHP won't execute any file with parse error.

This still means you can catch parse errors, but only in included/required files:

```
function shutdown() {
        $isError = false;
        if($error = error_get_last()){
            switch($error['type']){
                case E_ERROR:
                case E_CORE_ERROR:
                case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
                case E_USER_ERROR:
                case E_PARSE:
                    $isError = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if ($isError){
            echo "Script execution halted ({$error['message']})";
        }
        else {
            echo "Script completed";
        }
}


register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

require 'broken.php'; // File with parse error
```

Notice I added `E_PARSE` constant to your `switch()`, this is the error you get.